MUI with Preact & HTM No Build Setup
Preact shows you can use it with HTM for a no build setup here. Which works well on my phone since I haven't be able to get Vite to work because of symlinks.
MUI shows how to install and use it with Preact as well but not with HTM for a no build setup. https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/
I've tried import { Button } from '@mui/material/Button';
It's tried it without brackets and even importing the file directly with import { Button } from '../node_modules/@mui/material/Button.js';
Yet console still shows...

material-ui.development.js:1848 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
properties of undefined (reading 'useLayoutEffect')
at material-ui.development.js:1848:74
at material-ui.development.js:9:78
at material-ui.development.js:10:3   (anonymous) @ material-ui.development.js:1848   (anonymous) @
material-ui.development.js:9   (anonymous) @
material-ui.development.js:10
127.0.0.1/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier   "@mui/material/Button". Relative references must start with either
"/", "./", or "../".

What can I do to get this to work with Preact and htm for a no build setup?
Here's my code...
My package.json:
{
  "name": "project",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.001",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.19",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "latest",
    "@testing-library/react": "latest",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "latest",
    "htm": "^3.1.1",
    "preact": "^10.22.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
  }
}

My index.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Site title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, interactive-widget=resizes-content">
    <script src="js/standalone.module.js" type="module"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="module" src="components/App.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

My App.js:
import { html, render } from '../js/standalone.module.js';
import { Button } from '@mui/material/Button';

function ButtonUsage() {
  return html`
    <${Button} variant="contained">Hello world<//>
  `;
}

render(html`<${ButtonUsage} />`, document.getElementById('root'));


Before we get started, react-scripts, along with Babel, is build tooling. This makes your question a bit unclear. You shouldn't have it in a no-build setup.

To start with, a bare import specifier like @mui/material/Button is meant for use in Node or, somewhat recently, with import maps -- on it's own, it's an invalid specifier in the web.
Additionally, as MUI is a React lib, you need to set up aliases to preact/compat and it will not work out-of-the-box in a Preact app (as your errors show).
Here's an example:

note: I imagine js/standalone.module.js is htm/preact/standalone, which is better extracted to this form if we're using import maps.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Site title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no, interactive-widget=resizes-content">
    <script type="importmap">
      {
        "imports": {
          "preact": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2",
          "preact/": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2/",
          "react": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2/compat",
          "react/": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2/compat/",
          "react-dom": "https://esm.sh/preact@10.19.2/compat",
          "htm/preact": "https://esm.sh/htm@3.1.1/preact?external=preact",
          "@mui/material": "https://esm.sh/@mui/material?external=react,react-dom"
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="module" src="components/App.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Then in your script:
import { render } from 'preact';
import { html } from 'htm/preact';
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

function ButtonUsage() {
  return html`
    <${Button} variant="contained">Hello world<//>
  `;
}

render(html`<${ButtonUsage} />`, document.getElementById('root'));

Hope it helps!

Thanks. Question. How would I use useState or useEffect in this setup?
import { html, useState, useEffect } from 'htm/preact'; returns Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'htm/preact' does not provide an export named 'useEffect' (at App.js:2:26) in console.
Same with import { render, useState, useEffect } from 'preact';
returns Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'preact' does not provide an export named 'useEffect' (at App.js:1:28)

Lol nvm I figured it out using import { useState, useEffect } from 'preact/hooks';

Yup! A bit of a tangent: while htm/preact/standalone is great for one-off usage, problems come when you add dependencies (@mui/material) and other things that might need Preact. You'll either need to start aliasing everything to htm/preact/standalone, which is a bit fiddly, or add preact in addition, which can cause problems with hooks as Preact needs to be used as a singleton (only loaded once).  htm/preact/standalone therefore presents a bit of an issue as you add in more things and that's why we go with this approach, using htm/preact and preact separately.

Adding the ?alias=react:preact/compat,react-dom:preact/compat&external=preact querystring params to the whatever React component library you're using was the most helpful lesson here. FFR (and for future "searchability"), this fixes the following error: Uncaught InvalidCharacterError: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('[object Object]') is not a valid name.

That's not really what we'd recommend anymore, updated the answer accordingly. Better to alias via other entries to the import map as our docs show
